# Query_Posts Does Not Work If Post_type is not Post

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type

so i was trying filter a custom post-type, one i created by its post_id(154) and this was my query, but it did not work (query below).

```
query_posts('q=154')  //query_posts(array('post_id'=>154)) 
if(have_posts()){ the_post();
   $ar = types_render_field('job_posts', array('output'=>'html'));
    echo $ar;
 }
```

Then i tried this.. and it still refused to work(codebelow)

```
resetAll();
$q = new WP_Query(array('post_id' => 154));
if($q->have_posts()): $q->the_post();

    echo '<b>the title is<b> ' ; //. $q->the_title();
    $ar = types_render_field('job_posts', array('output'=>'html'));
                    echo $ar;

endif;
```

this was my final answer(code below) which worked... but its a work around because i had to loop through all the available results and filter just the required post with the desired ID, which is totally bad...

```
    resetAll();
            query_posts(array('post_type' => 'vacancy'));

            if(have_posts()):
                while(have_posts()): the_post();

                 if(get_the_id() == '154'):
                    ///echo '<b>the title is </b>' .get_the_title() .'//'. get_the_id();            
                    $ar = types_render_field('job_posts', array('output'=>'html'));
                    echo $ar;
                endif;

                endwhile;       
            endif;
```

i feel thats a bug coz i've spend countless hours on this line.... else if anyone has an alternative i'd like to know... thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just using `get_post($id)`?

```$post = get_post( 154 ); 
echo $post->post_title;
```

Comment: You really should [avoid to use query_posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).

Comment: interesting...i normally would prefer using WP_Query($args), but i'm yet to get the right way to achieve this, since on the background they all run through the $wpdb scope... i would try yours now and see but remember i'm trying to access a custom post type, which routes to the types_api plugin.

Comment: and please i forgot to emphasize on the method - resetAll(); its located in my functions.php file, and it just calls wp_reset_postdata(), and wp_reset_query()... i prefer it this way, since i just flush out all the data from the post object before performing any queries...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you've decided to use `query_posts()`.

You can use  `WP_Query` class or just `get_post()` (as mentioned in comments). You can use it like this:

```
$desiredPostQuery = new WP_Query(array(p=154, 'post_type=vacancy'));
$desiredPost = $desiredPostQuery->get_posts();
```

The other way is to use `get_post()`:

`$desiredPost = get_post(154);`

Reference in codex:
[get_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) and [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: yea.. i use WP_Query  most of the time, but then remember i have to call the types_render_field() from the wp-types api plugin, it assumes the ID has been set since it has access to the current $post object, get_post() doesnt create a scope since it just requests an ID..

Answer (score -1):

Please try using [`wp_reset_query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query). Please follow the link.

Comment: i have a method resetAll(); its located in my functions.php file,  it calls wp_reset_postdata(), and wp_reset_query()... so you'd know.